# Encoding issue with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm running into a encoding issue with BeautifulSoup. I'm trying to parse Open Graph titles but it's leaving out non-ascii characters.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
doc = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
doc.html.head.findAll('meta',attrs={'property':'og:title'})
```

For http://mattilintulahti.net/mediablogi/2013/02/11/19-asiaa-joita-et-tieda-mediayhtiosta-nimeltaan-red-bull/ it prints out the following for the content

```
19 asiaa joita et tied mediayhtist nimeltn Red Bull
```

Where the correct one is

```
19 asiaa joita et tiedä mediayhtiöstä nimeltään Red Bull
```

Any advice on how to get utf-8 to works properly?

Comment: What operating system? Works for me on Linux.

Comment: quick nit: find_all(..) is preferable to findAll(..) for pep8 reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not able to reproduce the problem:

```
import urllib2
import bs4 as bs
url = 'http://mattilintulahti.net/mediablogi/2013/02/11/19-asiaa-joita-et-tieda-mediayhtiosta-nimeltaan-red-bull/'
html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
doc = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
for meta in doc.html.head.findAll('meta', attrs={'property': 'og:title'}):
    print(meta.attrs['content'])
```

yields

```
19 asiaa joita et tiedä mediayhtiöstä nimeltään Red Bull
```

If this doesn't help, please show your your code.

Comment: You're correct, this actually works. I had accidentally copypasted one line too much when investigating this which messed up things:

    html = unicode(html,errors='ignore')